# Do I have to include a privacy policy even if the only network thing that my app does is purchase from the Windows Store itself?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, capability

The [rule 4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#acr_4_1) of the Windows Store says:

> 4.1 Your app must comply with the following privacy-related requirements:
>
> 4.1.1 Your app must have a privacy statement if it is network-capable
>
> If your app has the technical ability to transmit data, you must
>   maintain a privacy policy. You must provide access to your privacy
>   policy in the Description page of your app, as well as in the app’s
>   settings as displayed in the Windows Settings charm.
>
> App capability declarations that make your app network-capable
>   include: internetClient, internetClientServer and
>   privateNetworkClientServer.
>
> Your privacy policy must inform users of the personal information
>   transmitted by your app and how that information is used, stored,
>   secured and disclosed, and describe the controls that users have over
>   the use and sharing of their information, how they may access their
>   information, and it must comply with applicable laws and regulations.

In order to be able to do in-app purchases from the Windows Store itself, unless I'm mistaken you have to enable Internet capabilities.

This would mean that even if the only network-related thing I intend to do are the in-app purchases, I have to include a privacy policy anyway.

(and if this is correct, that would be understandable: if I enable Internet, the access is unrestricted, so my app *could* also do other things)

So, am I missing something, or is it really so (maybe instead of those permissions there are some more-specific ones)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows Store policies and is not programming (code) related according to the guidelines in the [help]. Questions about Windows Store should be directed to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, whenever you are using the internet access capability, you have to give a privacy policy as users have to know why and how the connection is used.